# Delete duplicates from `MySQL` and keep single record based on an order

Tags: mysql

I need to remove all the duplicates and keep only one with the highest amount . Perhaps I should do some kind of JOIN operation but I'm not very experienced with . I have this query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM invoices 
GROUP BY user 
ORDER BY  amount DESC
```

it queries all the rows, orders them by amount and "removes" the duplicates as it groups by user but obviously doesn't delete the duplicates. Any help is appreciated . To make it clear the duplicates must be deleted permanently. 
 Schema :

```
 user varchar(125), amount int
```

Comment: can you show sample records? what is the schema of your table? by delete you mean remove on the table of not shown on the result?

Comment: are you actually wanting to delete records? or just remove duplicates from your query?

Comment: your question is incomplete.

Comment: I need to delete the duplicates not to remove them from the query. I think it's quite clear that they are removed from the query as I use GROUP BY .

Answer (score 2):

If you do a `SELECT *` that's not going to filter out records, even with a `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT user, MAX(amount) amount
FROM  invoices
GROUP BY user
ORDER BY amount DESC
```

Comment: This does not answer the question; OP wants to remove non-`MAX` records.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk does he actually want to delete them? his SQL shows a SELECT statement. `keep only the row with the highest amount` translates to only return those in a SELECT statement, not a delete. It's unclear at best.

Comment: Question's title contains **keep single record based on an order**; to me this means remove everything but.

Comment: He says `single record` yet you're assuming `records` it's entirely subjective and unclear based on what he's provided.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk it will remove duplicates... from result set.

Comment: I need to delete the duplicate records from the table and keep only the highest amount. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that you won't get the desired result because of the way you're using `GROUP BY`. MySQL [extends it's functionality](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html). You want to always specify the columns being selected in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT col1, col2, AGGREGATE(col3)
FROM table
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

> **I need to select all the rows find duplicates**

To find the `MAX` amount for each `user`:

```
SELECT user, 
       Max(amount) AS amount 
FROM   invoices 
GROUP  BY user
```

> **and keep only the row with the highest amount**

**Option 1**

Use a `LEFT JOIN` (thanks JW):

```
DELETE    invoices
FROM      invoices
LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT user, MAX(amount) AS amount
     FROM invoices
     GROUP BY user) j 
          ON j.user = invoices.user 
              AND j.amount = invoices.amount
WHERE j.amount IS NULL
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce2f8/1

**Option 2**

Create a staging table:

```
CREATE TABLE invoices (
  user int,
  amount decimal(5,2));

INSERT INTO invoices VALUES
(1, 100.00),
(1, 200.00),
(1, 300.00);

CREATE TABLE invoicesStg (
  user int,
  amount decimal(5,2));

INSERT INTO invoicesStg
(SELECT user, MAX(amount) AS amount
FROM invoices
GROUP BY user);

TRUNCATE invoices;

INSERT INTO invoices
SELECT user, amount
FROM invoicesStg;

DROP TABLE invoicesStg;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0381e/1

Comment: i was wondering why you need to have extra table to store the max record for each user. your original answer is fine only that you need to use `RIGHT JOIN` and find null values.

Comment: @JW. For some reason the thought went through my mind that OP might not use caution when executing the query.

Comment: `RJ` removes the maximum amount value and which the OP don;t want.

Comment: @JW. doesn't his question say he wants the max amount?

Comment: what about this DELETE n1 FROM users n1, users n2 WHERE n1.amount < n2.amount AND n1.user = n2.user ?

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of just finding duplicates, you can try:

```
SELECT  id, COUNT(amount) AS cnt, MAX(amount) AS mx 
FROM    invoices 
GROUP   BY user HAVING cnt > 1 
ORDER   BY amount DESC
```

From there, you can proceed removing these records.

Comment: I don't think so. GROUP BY is placed right before the aggregate function so you can group the user distinctly before printing out how many duplicates one might have.

Comment: @TakenByForce you're grouping by user, but counting by user in your select statement. That won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the row with the highest amount, try this:

```
select *
from invoices
order by amount desc
limit 1
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "delete".  Do you really want to delete all rows but the one with the highest amount?

Comment: i think someone is using this question to mess around with people

Comment: @MattBusche . . . You can always delete your answer to get the points back.  The original question seems legit.  It's hard to butcher English quite like that.  I find the different interpretations interesting; none of the answers seems worthy of downvotes.

Comment: i'm not worried about the rep, but I agree neither of our answers are worthy of downvotes. There was another answer that was removed already that got downvoted.

Comment: @MattBusche the question is incomplete (*for me*) and because of that too many interpretations can arise. the downvoter only thinks of his own translation of the question.

Comment: @MattBusche the removed answer suggested to delete records completely ;s

Comment: @meze . . . The original question said "delete" and the question was then revised.  The downvotes actually occurred while the question still said "delete".  In other words, that answer might have been the most appropriate for the question at that time.  And yet, it was downvoted with no comments.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the only part that is clear is "I need to select" ;) Or was it added later?